# I'm trying to do npm install -g @angular/cli and an error appears : I'm tying npm cache clear, but same error appears. what will be the solution?

Tags: npm, angular-cli

D:\Angular\interpolation> npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

- @angular/cli@10.1.4
  updated 1 package in 18.702s

Comment: try uninstalling and re-installing nodejs and nom

Comment: Where is the error? I only see the warning for "this library is no longer supported"

Comment: #Elmehdi, not response same error

Comment: #Tyler ,not understand what you ask.?